# Cannot generate SOAP client on .net core 3 from WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a web service written on WCF. I am trying to generate the client by using "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider". My project is .net core 3 web api.
But I get this error
Warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='ILiveViewService']

Why is it trying to reference System.Web? It is a framework library. It is not part of the CORE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, trying to include a new WCF, but it didn't work, with the same error above.

The conflict was between the references `System.Web` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, probably when adding. It was giving conflict between both.

The solution was to remove any references from `System.Web` that I had on my controller.

Controller with error:

```
[ApiController]
public class TesteController: ControllerBase {}
```

Controller without error:

```
public class TesteController: Controller {}
```